# Redirect multiple folder to another folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have multiple folders inside a folder. I want my domain to redirect to the folders inside without having to put the main-folder name. Ex:
When I type the subdomain.com/folder1, it redirects to subdomain.com/folder/folder1
How can I do this in htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ /folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Understand this as just a very general hint. Without any more details in your question no specific answer is possible ...